# How to prevent having same values in angular reactive form? (36 input fileds)

Tags: angular

I'm using angular reactive form and I need to prevent any input from having the same value of other input(values should be numbers only (and decimals but I'm stuck there too)),
how can I make the form invalid if two or more inputs have the same value?

i'll show my code to help me adding any code:

example of three input in ts and html (out of 36):

in ts file:

```
this.voucherForm = new FormGroup({
        'Restaurant_Name': new FormControl(this.voucher.Restaurant_Name, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")),
        'Restaurant_VAT': new FormControl(this.voucher.Restaurant_VAT, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")),
        'Restaurant_Address': new FormControl(this.voucher.Restaurant_Address, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"))
});
```

in html:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Restaurant_Name" >
      </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">VAT</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName="Restaurant_VAT" >
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Restaurant_Address" >
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the submit button is disabled when form is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be solvable with a custom validator. The following might help

```
static matchControls(instantValidation: boolean, ...controlNames: string[]): ValidatorFn {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const controls = controlNames
        .map(name => formGroup.get(name));
      const match = controls
        .map(c => c.value)
        .reduce((prev, curr) => prev && curr && prev === curr);
      return match ? {matchControls: true} : null;
    };
  }
```

Comment: All values you put in thats what the "...controlNames: string[]" is for

Comment: matchControls(false, 'Restaurant_Name', 'Restaurant_VAT','Restaurant_Adress') for example

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom validator, which checks the current value against the other values of the input. Example:

```
this.voucherForm = new FormGroup({
    'Restaurant_Name': new FormControl(
        this.voucher.Restaurant_Name, 
        [
            Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")),
            // this validor chechs if the value is the same as the otehrs
            (c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
                const vatValue = this.voucherForm.value[this.voucher.Restaurant_VAT];
                const adressValue = this.voucherForm.value[this.voucher.Restaurant_Address];
                if(c.value === vatValue || c.value === adressValue) {
                    return {ValuesIdenticalError: true}
                } else  {
                    return undefinded;
                }
            }
        ]

    ...
    'Restaurant_VAT': new FormControl(this.voucher.Restaurant_VAT, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")),
    'Restaurant_Address': new FormControl(this.voucher.Restaurant_Address, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"))
});
```

Comment: that's excellent but I have 36 input field. should i code this validator for all?

Comment: for 36 this is not the best solution (I assumed it was for the 3 you mentined in the question). In this case have to define the validator outside (e.g const sameValueValidator = .... ). and then check all values, if any of them are the same and if any of the same values is the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Add disable property on button like this

```
[disabled] = "formName.invalid"
```

Comment: I need to validate the input values not the button

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add an `onChange()` in both field that haven't to be the same and everytime the input gets updated it will test if its value is equal to the other input value.

if `true` then you set the form to invalid or you show an error

Comment: all 34 inputs should not be equal

Answer (score 0):

Validators in Angular are weird, you can't really see out of them to other controls inside that code.  I think the best way for this is to have a form level validator.

```
 this.myForm.FormGroup({
    restaurantName: new FormControl(this.voucher.restaurantName, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")),
    restaurantVat: new FormControl(this.voucher.restaurantVat, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"))
    etc...
}, { validators: this.myFormValidator });

myFormValidator: ValidatorFn = (controls: FormGroup): {[s: string]: boolean} => {
    // you can access all form controls through the parameter
    const restaurantName = controls.get('restaurantName').value;
    const restaurantVat = controls.get('restaurantVat').value;

    if (restaurantName == restaurantVat) {
        // oh no, this is bad! you can set errors for whatever controls are bad here
        controls.get('restaurantVat').setErrors({'vatMatchesName': true});
    } else {
        // make sure to remove the error if it passes or it will stick around 
        controls.get('restaurantVat').setErrors(null);
    }
}
```

Now I use Angular Material controls (mat-select, matInput, mat-checkbox, etc...) so to display the errors I use mat-error.  I add a function to determine if the error should be displayed or not

```
 onError(controlName: string, errorName: string) {
    return this.form.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  }
```

Finally I use the mat-error to display the error on my control

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Restaurant VAT" formControlName="restaurantVat"
    <mat-error *ngIf="onError('restaurantVat', 'vatMatchesName')">This value can't match another value</mat-error>
</mat-form-field
```